# WHERE inside CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen lots of posts about putting CASE statements inside WHERE clauses.  However, in my case, I want to put a WHERE statement inside a CASE statement, which I don't think can be done.

My situation is that I have a view that is going on many, many databases.  In half of them, I need to have a WHERE clause.  In the other half, I don't need the WHERE clause.  Leaving it in isn't harmful, in that I don't get bad data, but it slows the query down considerably given that it has to read and sort a large table when it is unnecessary.

```
Status_Table
ID    Status
1     Active
2     Inactive
3     Unknown    --this row of data will not exist in some DBs

Item_table
Item_ID    Status    value1    value2
1001          3      .....     .....
1002          1      .....     .....
```

What I want to do is something like this.

```
-- big nasty ugly query with various CTEs, selects, and joins
CASE    WHEN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Status_table) = 3
        THEN WHERE Item_Table.Status != 3
        ELSE WHERE 1=1
END
```

Ultimately, I can probably swing this by constructing the query using dynamic SQL, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Your case statement doesnt make sense. Which value do you want to set when MAXID = 3? And then just write the same expression but with != 3 and set your value

Comment: CASE is an expression which is used to return a scalar value. WHERE is a clause which is used to filter the results of a select statement. Simply put what you are trying to do cannot be done the way you are trying to do it. Dynamic sql is going to be required but you can't do that in a view. Perhaps you need to reevaluate what is going on here.

Comment: Are you trying to exclude the `max(ID)` from `Status_Table` or will this value be known already in `Item_Table`. If so, just filter in a normal `WHERE` based on your `Item_Table` value. You could also probably use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the `MAX(ID)`.

Comment: Yes, @plaidDK, I understand this syntax doesn't make sense.  What I want is a conditional WHERE clause.  I want to have a where clause in some cases, and not in others, based on the MAX value in another table.

And yes, I wanted to avoid dynamic SQL since this is a view, and moving it to a stored procedure comes with some other issues in my environment.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to the other table ON the `ID`, then use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ID DESC )`, then filter out the first row of that subquery, ie `rn<>1`.

Comment: @Shawn, but then I have to sort the large table regardless.  That is exactly what I am trying to avoid.  I can just use a (SELECT MAX() FROM ..) within a WHERE clause to get the data I need.  But I don't want to search a huge table when I know beforehand that I don't need to.  In other words, I know if the MAX value of Status = x, I need not do a WHERE at all.  If it's > x, I need the WHERE.

Comment: @RobertSievers I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are trying to do. The SQL Optimizer will do a pretty efficient job of filtering the records you need if you write the query well. There shouldn't be any excess "sorting" on the huge table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build a conditional `WHERE` clause, yes? I'd think something like this would work pretty well for what you want to do:

```
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Status_table WHERE ID = 3) 
        AND Item_Table.Status != 3)
        OR
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Status_table WHERE ID = 3)
```

Comment: That's it!  I knew there had to be a logical way to handle that, but I just was lost in the fog.  The query optimizer should drop out the table scan (or index scan) if the first EXISTS clause fails.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8caa9/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Status_Table ( ID int, [Status] varchar(30) ) ;
INSERT INTO Status_Table ( ID, [Status] )
VALUES 
  ( 1,'Active' ), (2,'Inactive'), (3,'Unknown')
;

CREATE TABLE Item_table ( Item_ID int, [Status] int, value1 varchar(10), value2 varchar(10) ) ;
/* NOTE: Item_table.[Status] should be a descriptive name, like [StatusID], or something not the same name as a different datatype column in the relation table. */
INSERT INTO Item_Table ( Item_ID, [Status], value1, value2 )
VALUES (1001,3,'Bill','Exclude')
  ,(1002,1,'Ted','Include')
  ,(1003,3,'Rufus','Exclude')
  ,(1004,2,'Jay','Include')
  ,(1005,5,'Bob','BadRecord')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s1.Item_ID, s1.Status, s1.Value1, s1.Value2
FROM (
  SELECT i.Item_ID, i.Status, i.Value1, i.Value2
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s.ID DESC) AS rn
  FROM Item_Table i
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN Status_Table s ON i.[Status] = s.ID
) s1
WHERE s1.rn <> 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8caa9/2/0)**:

```
| Item_ID | Status | Value1 |  Value2 |
|---------|--------|--------|---------|
|    1004 |      2 |    Jay | Include |
|    1002 |      1 |    Ted | Include |
```

Answer (score 0):

If its performance your after start using DECLARE and SET.
It only needs to execute ONCE!!!

```
DECLARE @UnkownExists AS INT
    SET @UnkownExists = (select count(*) from Status_table where ID = 3)

-- big nasty ugly query with various CTEs, selects, and joins
  WHERE (@UnkownExists=1 AND Item_Table.Status != 3) OR @NoUnknown=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Status_table) = 3 
    THEN 3 
    ELSE (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM Status_table) --Invalid value that will not exist
END <> Item_Table.Status
```